# Как устранить проблему C:\___Programming_apps\Python\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in '' в Sublime text 3

Tags: python-3.x, sublime-text-3

Хочу перейти в ST 3 для программирования на Питоне. Все необходимые плагины для этого уже скачал (anaconda), однако не могу запустить программу. Что делать? Как прописать путь к интерпретатору?

Comment: я может не понимаю чего-то, но как связана анаконда с sublime text?

Comment: Приведите полное сообщение об ошибке (скопируйте один в один). Какие конкретно действия вы выполняли перед тем как ошибку получили (опишите подробно по шагам).